# MERN Stack : Trying to delete item using Redux, but state isn't changing?

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

I've been trying to learn the MERN stack by following code using Traversy Media's MERN stack tutorial. I'm currently on [Part 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO6akRGXhx8&list=PLillGF-RfqbbiTGgA77tGO426V3hRF9iE&index=6) where I am trying to delete an item using Redux; however, when I click the item to delete it, nothing happens.

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong using the Redux DevTools on Chrome and when I try to delete an item, under the "Action" tab DELETE_ITEM appears and the action has the type : "DELETE_ITEM" and payload with the id of the item I clicked, which all seems correct.

However, when I go to check the "Diff" tab, it just says (states are equal) which I'm assuming means that everything is working correctly until I reach the itemReducers.js because the state isn't showing up.

I've checked and rechecked the code for any typos but it all seems correct to me. Maybe I'm just missing something as I've been messing around with the code for the longest time trying to figure out what is wrong?

ShoppingList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";

import uuid from 'uuid';

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getItems, deleteItem } from "../actions/itemActions";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  item : state.item
});

class ShoppingList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItems();
  }

  onDeleteClick = id => {
    this.props.deleteItem(id);
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props.item;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Button 
          style={{ margin: '2rem 0' }}
          onClick={() => {
            const name = prompt('Enter new item');
            if (name) {
              this.setState(state => ({
                items : [...state.items, { id : uuid.v4(), name }]
              }))
            }
          }}>
            Add Item
        </Button>
        <ListGroup>
          {items.map(({id, name}) => {
            return (
              <ListGroupItem key={ id }>
                { name }
                <Button 
                  style={{ float: 'right' }}
                  onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, id)}>×</Button>
              </ListGroupItem>
            )
          })}
        </ListGroup>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

ShoppingList.propTypes = {
  getItems : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  item : PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getItems, deleteItem })(ShoppingList);
```

itemActions.js

```
export const getItems = () => {
  return {
    type: "GET_ITEMS"
  }
}

export const addItem = () => {
  return {
    type : "ADD_ITEM"
  }
}

export const deleteItem = id => {
  return {
    type : "DELETE_ITEM",
    playload: id
  }
}
```

itemReducer.js

```
import uuid from 'uuid';

const initialState = {
  items : [
    { id: uuid.v4(), name : 'steak'},
    { id: uuid.v4(), name : 'chicken'},
    { id: uuid.v4(), name : 'eggs'}
  ]
}

const itemReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_ITEMS" :
      return {...state};
    case "ADD_ITEM" :
      state = {};
      break;
    case "DELETE_ITEM" : 
      return {
        ...state,
        items : state.items.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload)
      };
    default :
      return {...state};
  }
}

export default itemReducer;
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from  'redux-thunk';
import itemReducer from './reducers/itemReducer';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

let store = createStore(combineReducers({item : itemReducer}), initialState, compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
));

export default store;
```

Comment: Haven't thoroughly looked at this yet but can you check and verify the spelling?  You have a typo: "playload"

Comment: Just saw this and I checked my code, fixed that typo and it works. Literally spent the past two day trying to figure out was wrong. Welp, now I feel dumb. Thanks for the second set of eyes!

Comment: Happens to all of us, no worries!